# How to automatically kill buffer on terminal process exit in Emacs

Tags: emacs, process, exit, kill

How can I automatically kill the terminal buffer when the process associated with it ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I can use process sentinels for that and set it using `term-exec-hook`

```lisp
(add-hook 'term-exec-hook (lambda ()
            (let* ((buff (current-buffer))
                 (proc (get-buffer-process buff)))
            (lexical-let ((buff buff))
               (set-process-sentinel proc (lambda (process event)
                            (if (string= event "finished\n")
                                       (kill-buffer buff))))))))
```

Answer (score 6):

I found much simpler method, define an advice on `term-handle-exit`

```
(defadvice term-handle-exit
  (after term-kill-buffer-on-exit activate)
(kill-buffer))
```